# How to prevent extracting irrelevant leaguages by google vision

Tags: python, google-api, ocr, text-extraction, google-vision

I am using Google vision on python to extract text from id card.

I will cut the the picture as below and send it to google API
[image]

Since the id card contains only English, chinese, numbers and some common symbol (e.g. - * ()), I set the languageHints as ["en","zh-Hant-HK"].

```
data = {
    'features':{
        'type': 'TEXT_DETECTION'
    },
    'image':{
        'content': encoded_string.decode("utf-8")
    },
    'imageContext':{
        'languageHints': ["en","zh-Hant-HK"]
    }
}
```

However, the google API returns some irrelevant leaguages like this:

```
"CHAN, Mang H\u1ed3\nHo"
```

Sometimes it returns unicode which is not English or chinese.

In this case, \u1ed3 is ồ (LATIN SMALL LETTER O WITH CIRCUMFLEX AND GRAVE)

How can I prevent the case like this?

---

//update

I have tried to do some image processing (like threshold and increasing contrast) to remove the background and make the text sharper before I send it to google API.

- Processing with gray and threshold

[image]

- Processing with gray and increasing contrast

[image]

It still consider the o is a LATIN letter.

Comment: Maybe can try to remove the language hint... according to google documentation "However, in most cases, an empty value yields the best results since it enables automatic language detection. " [Google Vision info page](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr?hl=zh-tw#specify_the_language_optional)

Comment: @H3coder I try to add languageHints because I met some case with upper case O that the api reading as Cyrillic letter O. After I add languageHints, it handles the upper case O correctly and no more Cyrillic letter. However, it read lower case o as Latin letter this time and  I cannot fix it by removing the languageHints.

Comment: It could be because of the background. What if you adjust the contrast of the file first? I saved the picture to my computer, use an image app to [increase contrast to 90 and got a very clean result](https://imgur.com/a/eIyIdXW). You can save this picture and send to your code.

Comment: @H3coder I had try to use your picture and it still returns \u1ed3. I make some update on this post as well.

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you anymore since I don't have access or worked with Google vision. Another venue might be to try [OpenCV OCR with Tesseract](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/text-detection-and-extraction-using-opencv-and-ocr/)